# How do I link my flight schedule right to my agent?

Tags: database, simulation, anylogic, agent, discrete

Im new to Anylogic.
I am creating a airport.
I want get the Attribut called flug of my passenger that tell the remaining seconds till boarding.
I have already created Pedestrian agents with a database, which this Attribut flug. If I want to retrieve this parameter at selectOutput, with time()>= agent.flug; the system always tells me: "agent can not be resolved to a variable", if I use time()>= ped.flug; I don't get this error message, but the parameter is not retrieved at all, respectively at my query for the remaining seconds until departure the corresponding action doesn't happen. Can this be due to the fact, that my agents are connected at the source Block by another Exel.

[where my condition is asked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2zIj.png)

[Table for my attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2JKK.png)

[Table for my schedule, when passenger enter the airport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv89w.png)

[my agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrzXW.png)

I looked in similarly simulation and these were able to get the Parameter with agent.flug. Although I suggested that I am only able to use ped instead of agent because I used to define this in one of my functions.
[my function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENwmu.png)

Answer (score -1):

Learn about the [magic lightbulb](https://www.anylogic.com/blog/the-magic-light-bulb-by-benjamin-schumann/) first.

Then, you will see why you need the `ped` keyword.

In condition 4, you can also see a small warning flag. Hover over that and it will likely point out that you cannot have `;` at the end of conditions. Remove it and it may work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: likely your flwo chart block does not expect the correct agent type, check that out (did you define a custom ped type? then you need to tell the flow chart block about it)

Comment: The 'paxex[..]' population exists separately from the flowchart. PedSource generates new agents and the 'flug' parameter is never assigned for the peds. So I need to assign the value for flight to the agent, but how do I do it so that it fits the „Table for my attribute“

Comment: Pls always open new issues for new questions, SOF does not work like a forum. See https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow